# Is there a way to tell if a random element's type in a list is MethodInfo?

Tags: c#, list, types

I have a List

```
List<Type> types = new List<Type>();
```

called types in which I will store random types including a MethodInfo on the first index.
I want to do something like this:

```
types[0] == typeof(MethodInfo)
```

to check if the element's type is a MethodInfo or not.

My problem is that this expression always evaluates to false, and i don't know the reasoning behind it.

Update
The full code:

```
List<Type> types = new List<Type>() { typeof(Person) };

var personMethods = typeof(Person).GetMethods().Where(m => m.GetCustomAttribute<MethodMarkerAttribute>() != null).ToArray();

foreach (var personMethod in personMethods)
{
 types.Add(personMethod.GetType());
}

int counter = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < types.Count; i++)
{
 if (types[i] == typeof(MethodInfo))
 {
  counter++;
 }
}
Console.WriteLine("{0} Method info(s) were found.", counter);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: How exactly are you putting a `MethodInfo` in a `List<Type>` in the first place?

Comment: If you added the Type as `types.Add(typeof(MethodInfo));`, then `var isIt = types[0] == typeof(MethodInfo);` should return `true`.

Comment: Or the Type of an object, as in `types.Add(someObjectInstance.GetType());` .

Comment: I uploaded the code, the problem is that the counter stays at 0, but I want it to be at 2.

Comment: Is `GetMethods()` even finding the correct methods?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer:

```
methods[0].MemberType == MemberTypes.Method
```